# Fedora yum repositories?

Tags: linux, fedora, repository, yum

Greetings all,

I come from Debian world and I installed Fedora 12 in my Macbook Pro.
When I try to install software , I noticed that I cant find the huge software list which had in Debian. (first thing I found missing was bioinformatics tool called blast which can be found in debian repo http://packages.debian.org/sid/blast2 )
I used rpmfusion as :

```
su -c 'rpm -Uvh http://download1.rpmfusion.org/free/fedora/rpmfusion-free-release-stable.noarch.rpm http://download1.rpmfusion.org/nonfree/fedora/rpmfusion-nonfree-release-stable.noarch.rpm'
```

but couldn't see many of packages found in Debian.

Is there any single massive repository for Fedora like in Debian ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can get blast from the [ncbi ftp server](ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/blast/executables/blast+/LATEST/).

Comment: Debian's policy is to package up anything that compiles, Fedora is pickier there...

Answer (score 2):

Yes: It *is* the Fedora repositories. There may of course be differences between Fedora and Debian, since otherwise they wouldn't both exist.

And of course if you find something is missing, feel free to package it and submit it back to Fedora so that other people can take advantage of it too.

Answer (score 1):

Fedora doesn't have the same central repository philosophy as Debian. It relies more on the upstream developers, so you can get newer packages at the theoreticaly risk of less compatibility.
I typically recommend [rpmforge](http://rpmrepo.org/RPMforge) to people, it's large and well enough used to be good quality.

Answer (score 0):

The repositories I use are:

- google
- fedora
- rpmfusion-free-updates
- Dropbox
- rpmfusion-nonfree-updates
- rpmfusion-free
- adobe-linux-i386
- updates
- google-chrome
- rpmfusion-nonfree

There are several others to choose from though. A quick online search for the above should get you going.